# How to set properties of value types (e.g. Point) using reflection?

Tags: vb.net, reflection, properties

We created a new `Drawing.Point` dynamically at runtime and it works fine. Now we want to set the properties "X" and "Y" at runtime. 
We tried to do it like this:

```
    Public Function SetObjectProperty(propertyName As String, value As Integer, refObj As Object)

    Dim propertyInfo As PropertyInfo = refObj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName)

    If propertyInfo IsNot Nothing Then

        propertyInfo.SetValue(refObj, value, Nothing)
        Return refObj
    End If
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

But it didn't work. The properties aren't set with the values.
Did we miss anything?

Comment: Why not just call pointVariable.X = 10 ?

Comment: Because we were told to stay generic. And now we are creating the object dynamically related on what our reader gets out of a xml file. So we can't code it like that, because in the next loop there may be an other method (like "Color") which needs to set something else then the properties of a Point Object :/

I just read in the console that the value propertyInfo is "Int32 X" instead of only "X" could that be the problem and how can we solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `System.Drawing.Point` is a value type. When you pass this value into `SetValue`, it is boxed. The value is changed on the boxed object but the original value is not changed. Here is a modification that does the boxing before changing the value. You will also need the `ByRef` parameter modifier:

```
Public Function SetObjectProperty(propertyName As String, value As Integer, ByRef refObj As Object)
    Dim type = refObj.GetType()
    Dim propertyInfo As PropertyInfo = type.GetProperty(propertyName)

    If propertyInfo IsNot Nothing Then
        If type.IsValueType Then
            Dim boxedObj As ValueType = refObj
            propertyInfo.SetValue(boxedObj, 25)
            refObj = boxedObj
        Else
            propertyInfo.SetValue(refObj, value)
        End If
        Return refObj
    End If
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

You can use it as before:

```
Dim p As Point
SetObjectProperty("X", 25, p)
```

Btw, think about if you really need the return value. It does not seem to be necessary.

Comment: Ok thank you! That is what I was looking for. He is changing my X-Value now. ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The VALUE must be a Drawing.Point() Type, not an Integer.
You may utilize something like

```
Public Function SetObjectProperty(propertyName As String, value As Point, refObj As Object)

Dim propertyInfo As PropertyInfo = refObj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName)

If propertyInfo IsNot Nothing Then

    propertyInfo.SetValue(refObj, value.X, Nothing)
    Return refObj
End If
Return Nothing
```

Above, you can utilize *value.X* or even only *value* to get both coordinates.

Comment: Ok thank you that looks like what we need.   But can you explain the SetValue Parameters? At this point the "refObj" is our Drawing.Point-Object and the value is an Integer. The propertyInfo is the property which should be changed like "X".   What do we need to change here?      Do I get it right, to change the properties of a Drawing.Point I first need to create a Drawing.Point? :/ Isn't there a way to just get a Integer Value in there?

Comment: The reason is about the Object is a Drawing-Point type, the "Value" of SetValue must accomplish this. Although "X" and "Y" are Integers/Int32 and although the method "SetValue" also denotes an Integer, you must respect the TYPE of the "refObj" - and if you utilize VALUE.X you will be passing an Integer piece of that structure (X). Drawing.Point-type objects require a Drawing-Point structure, even if you utilize only one of its coordinates (an integer). The same like Position and Location in forms: they require a "PositionCoordinate-Like" type to function.

Comment: Ok right. But than I can't get it really dynamic. Because the Drawing.Point I would call in SetValue must have been declared before and that's the problem we have right now. Setting the properties dynamic depending on what we gonna get from the xml. :/

Comment: Hmmm... I didn´t understand exactly, BUT I will try to solve:  you must declare a variable of point-type, like:  Dim Sample as Point = Nothing.  In the runtime, probably you will get both coordinates as Integer.  If so, you just have to make smething like this before set the properties:  Sample.X = Integer1,  Sample.Y = Integer2  .  Is it?

Comment: Thanks David :) I really appreciate your help. But I think we solved it, it was the problem with the boxed object like Nico said. Sry for taking your time and thanks for your help :)